# How to get transparent scrollbars in webkit overlay

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, overlay

I've looked around a bit, but haven't found an example that works -- in Chrome at least.  I can set the color on the -webkit-scrollbar (see plunker), and it allows for setting an alpha value, but the text underneath does not show through, which seems kind of important if you are doing an overlay.

```css
    .main::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.1);
    }

    .main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

    .main {
      white-space: nowrap;
      height: 100px;
      overflow-y: overlay;
      background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5 Resize the  window so that some text is under the green, supposedly transparent, scrollbar)
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>etc</div>
      <div>etc</div>
      <div>etc</div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HPchLXPzXxPFHcqwY5R2?p=preview)

Comment: Why don't you add a `padding-right` to the body?

Comment: That's a solution, but its a pretty clunky one. This would require adding more padding than normal because the scrollbar _might_ be there.  I'm looking for something like [perfect-scrollbar](http://utatti.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/), but without all the [caveats](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/wiki/Caveats).

Comment: As per my limited understanding, this is the only possible solution. If you inspect the element, you could see the scroll bar being added as a `psuedo-element`, which consumes the width within the page, causing a horizontal scroll. Its still unclear to me why the `opacity` or `transparent background` or even the `z-index`is not applicable to it. But, atleast to prevent the horizontal scroll, its advised to add a `padding-right`. Hope this helps. Let me know.

Comment: The point of using the `overflow-y: overlay` is that it does _not_ consume any width. The horizontal scrollbar only shows up after the text has gone beyond (i.e. to the right) of the vertical scrollbar. That is desirable.  However, because it is not transparent, you also can't see the text, which is _not_ desirable.